# SubSonic 3 and inlinequery

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Where is InlineQuery on SubSonic 3.0 or is there a new equivalient?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now called [CodingHorror](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/CodingHorror) (even though the source file is still called [InlineQuery.cs](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/0f6248f9ee1e30287140932ca051e1992c70da0d/SubSonic.Core/Query/InlineQuery.cs))

Comment: Thanks, I wished Rob had kept it the same. At least it would have been consistent.

Comment: True, but on the upside, maybe the compiler errors due to the name change allow people to go over all of the InlineQueries in their application and consider if they are really needed or can be replaced e.g. with the new LINQ Support :)

Comment: I find it strange that Rob has put it in the namespace called codinghorror. Does he not like his old code?
Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: The namespace codinghorror is a reference to both the book Code Complete and the blog by a different author. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000292.html

Comment: It got stripped and I don't know why - I'll add it back.